# "At the Passing" Or "On the Passing"

Tags: differences, prepositions

Steve Ballmer writes:

> “I want to express my deepest condolences **at the passing** of Steve Jobs, one of the founders of our industry and a true visionary. My heart goes out to his family, everyone at Apple and everyone who has been touched by his work.”

I can't say if it's wrong, but what is the difference between "on the passing" and "at the passing"? As most other websites use "on the passing".

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=condolences+on%2C+condolences+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2):

The preposition *on* usually goes with *condolences*.

Other phrases or words referring to death can be inserted here:

> I wish to express my **condolences on** *your recent loss* | *the death of your father* | *the passing of Steve Jobs*.

There is no difference in meaning between *at* and *on* in this instance but *on* is preferred.

Comment: I dispute that *on* is preferred. Searching Google Books for *"on/at the passing of xxx"* with various "disambiguating" values for *"xxx"* (such as *John, Mr, Sir,* etc.) shows no such preference - if anything, it seems to me that *"at"* actually occurs slightly more often.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The ngarm inserted at the top by Armen shows "on" slightly more often.

Comment: @Mohammad: There are many different constructions where Armen's shorter search term **condolences on/at** will favour **on**, when it's not actually the context we're looking at here. That's why I specifically searched for both versions followed by **"the passing of xxx"**, for several different values of **xxx** that could *only* indicate the actual name of an individual who had died.